# Dalli Server Not Found When Running Delayed_Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached, delayed-job

When running a job with delayed_job, I get errors when trying to access the Dalli Cache.

The Dalli cache is initialized in environment.rb with the following...

```
CACHE = Dalli::Client.new(['localhost:11211'], {:namespace=>my_namespace_method})
```

When the code executes `CACHE.get 'my_key'` in my rails app, everything runs fine.

When it runs in a delayed_job worker, it errors with `No Server Available`

Other info that might help:

- I have confirmed that the memcached server is running and is accessible via telnet on localhost:11211
- We're running Ruby 1.9.2 under rvm